# Have middleware execute once per-query and not for every resolver

Tags: typegraphql

I am looking for a way to have a database call be made once for an entire query, and multiple resolvers use the data within context. The issue I am running into is that middleware seems to be called per-resolver and not once.

Is it possible to have middleware / some code only fire once per request, rather than fore each resolver?

Currently, the only I am achieving this is with external express-based middleware...

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag in the context. Something similar to:

```js
export const oncePerRequestMiddleware = (resolve, parent, args, context, info) => {
  if (!context.isRequestProcessed) {
    context.isRequestProcessed = true;
    // do you db call here
  }

  resolve(parent, args, context, info);
}
```

Personally, I ended up using a middleware at the `express middleware` level instead of at the `GraphQL middleware` level.